# asymmetric encryption using AES for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios4, aes, encryption-asymmetric

Team,

I would like to have asymmetric encryption using AES algorithm for iPhone application using Objective C. 
I have widely seen symmetric encryption using AES, so im not sure about the support for asymmetric encryption with AES. Kindly suggest me on this.

Comment: AES is NOT an asymmetric encryption algorithm. Use RSA or any other asymmetric algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

AES is a symmetric cipher. It can't simply be used an an asymmetric (i.e., public-key) capacity.

I am guessing the reason for your question is the issue of key exchange - such that you can establish an AES-encrypted connection without having to rely on a pre-shared key.

Numerous valid approaches exist, but I'll just hit on two:

1. Take a look at or Diffie-Hellman. You can get both sides of a connection to agree on a key without actually having to exchange that key. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie–Hellman_key_exchange
2. RSA. I'm a fan of Botan. It's free. It works. You can generate public/private key pairs on both sides, exchange the public keys, then securely exchange private keys, and then start AES. http://botan.randombit.net/pubkey.html

As always, this advice needs to be accompanied with a warning: it's very easy to do this incorrectly and largely (or entirely) thwart your security efforts. Tread carefully.